# Read odd addresses, half words?

Tags: assembly, cross-platform, endianness, cpu-architecture, word-size

It's common knowledge that many CPU architectures (ARM, PPC) can not read odd addresses but will generate an exception if forced too, and yet others can, but do so slightly slower. (x86)

But is there any CPU which can only address full 32 bit (or even larger!) words? I.e. it can not address 16 bit words?  Perhaps amd64?

I am trying to write a portable yet fast C malloc like allocator and want to align my memory accesses properly. Currently I am targeting ARM, i386 and amd64, and these I could look up characteristics for but thought it would be nice to keep an eye open.

I guess a concrete way to put my question would be;

is there a CPU were reading 16 bits from address 0x2 (assuming for the sake of the argument that the address range near 0 is valid in general, I know some CPUs do not use the first page) would give a bus error, where CPU = any of MIPS, ARM, x86, amd64, 68k, 88000, SH, OpenRISC, Sparc, PPC, Cell/SPE?

(I am looking at this whole thing from a C programmer's point of view, by the way. So I assume the C compiler gives me all the normal C types, like char, uint32_t etc.)

Comment: What about DSP style units? Also in b4 what is your programming question?

Comment: DSP style units, I know very little about. @CaptainGiraffe

Comment: Feel free to suggest another CPU to the list in the question. @CaptainGiraffe

Comment: Cell's SPEs can only read/write 16-byte quad-words :)  (obviously you can code around that restriction, as I imagine you could do on most any arch)

Comment: @JasonD, the SPE, apparently can be coded with a standard C compiler ( http://jk.ozlabs.org/docs/cell-spe-toolchain/ ) so I included it in my list of interest. If you make your comment an answer and elaborate a little, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cell's SPEs only have 16-byte quad-word load/store, and those must be aligned on 16-byte boundaries.

If you need to address at finer granularity, you have to read-modify-write, and use bit-masks to only update the relevant parts of the data.

Obviously in C/C++ the compiler will assist with that, and there is support in the instruction set for generating and using masks.

For your example of reading 16-bits from address '2', you would have to read 128-bits from address '0' and mask out the bits you need. If you wanted to write 16-bits to address '2', you would need to read all 128-bits first, then update the appropriate 16-bits, and write the whole lot back.

Comment: Didn't think about SPEs originally, but it's in every PS3 seven times over, so if fulfills my original requirement for being "reasonably common". Also, your explanation is simple. Accepting.

Comment: Consider this: do 16 bit quantities really exist on Cell SPEs?

Comment: @KevinA.Naudé, I'll give you that I could have been more stringent in defining semantics, but I had a hard time finding words for this question at all...  If we go with the answer "yes", then you argue for pretty much the opposite of JasonD. But I understand from your question that you mean "no". Nevertheless, I much prefer JasonD's answer.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant What I am pointing out is that the example of SPEs don't apply. It cannot address individual 16 bit values because they don't exist. It deals with vectors of 8x16-bit values as single units. So if you are needing an example, we need to look further. (I'm sure we agree on the semantics, though.)

Comment: 16 bit values exist in C. uint16_t. I see this from a C programmers perspective. @KevinA.Naudé

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant No problem. A *suitable* C compiler can always iron out any misaligned memory access, as Jason pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the early IBM Power processors could only read/write on item-size boundaries, but would handle unaligned data with a trap (exception) handler.  (And I think there was even one early version that would say "OK" and silently give you the contents of the aligned word, ignoring the low-order bits of your address.)

Pretty sure the old IBM 7000 series boxes could only read/write a full word on a 36-bit boundary (the word size), simply because there was no concept of an address more granular than that.  But I believe they had read/write low/high halfword operations.

The HP 2100 series processors, IIRC, only had word (16 bit) addresses, but could do byte indexing.  However, the index was only interpreted as a byte index for byte ops -- otherwise it was a word index.

In terms of aligning mallocs, though, you generally should align on a cache line boundary.  Otherwise it's hard to prevent cache thrashing is an MP environment.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the cache line thingy, but my allocator also has to be very compact.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant - It's hard to over-emphasize the importance of "the cache line thingy".  It can easily make a factor of 10 difference in performance.

Comment: I will benchmark different "cache line thingys" in my code, so no worries. :) In the end I may go for a less compact alignment if it's faster.  Not accepting your answer because the CPU examples were so old, but other than that, your answer is definitely "accept worthy". Thanks.

Comment: Not that I don't love lore about old computers. Wonder how the VAX instruction set fits here. In junior high I took naps on top of a VAX 11/780. SO I might not be as old as your T-shirts, but maybe almost. :)

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant - Never played with the VAX, though I walked by one once.

Answer (score 0):

If you can address a 16-bit quantity, then you can definitely read 16-bit aligned quantities.  I think you are probably assuming that you will have a byte addressable address space.  You may not, so caution is advised.  It is definitely conceivable that some architectures (particular embedded ones) may not be byte or even 16-bit addressable -- although I don't know specific (and current) examples.

Does that actually matter?  If you happen to have a machine that is word addressable, with a 32-bit *addressable* word size, then you could never actually address only 16 bits anyway.  Be careful with sizeof, though.

You asked about the amd64 (x86-64).  It has no restriction on memory aligned access, but you may lose cycles for misaligned access.  Keep in mind that misaligned accesses are never going to be portable.

UPDATE: What is an aligned address?

An aligned address of type T is any address that is a multiple of sizeof(T), where sizeof(T) is the number of addressable units the value occupies.  For example, if you have a 32-bit word size in a byte addressable space, the aligned addresses are at least every multiple of 4.  However, if the machine is addressable in 16-bit units, then every address that is a multiple of 2 will be an aligned address for 32-bit quantities.

If you are reading 16-bit quantities, there are three cases:

1. Byte addressing: odd addresses are potentially misaligned.  An architecture is free to treat these as aligned, but does not have too.
2. Addressable units are 16-bit: all addresses are align for 16-bit quantities.
3. Addressable units are larger: you don't actually have 16-bit quantities.  They are silently larger.

UPDATE 2: Is there a CPU were reading 16 bits from address 0x2 (assuming that address range is valid) would give a bus error?

There cannot ever be such a CPU, unless the addressable unit is below 8 bits.  The reason is that the alignment of address 0x2 is 2 addressable units.  If the addressable unit is 8-bits, then it is 16-bit aligned.

In addition, strange values for the addressable unit size are ruled out by the intention of 16 bits.  If 16 bit values are real quantities of the architecture, the the addressable unit must be a factor of 16.  So it could only be 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16 bits.  If it happens to be higher, the alignment is trivially satisfied.

Since an architecture that addresses less than 8 bits is not worth the trouble, you are all but guaranteed that the address 0x2 will be an aligned address for 16 bit quantities.

Comment: Is that really so?  I mean on 68000 you can certainly address and express odd 8-bit quantities, but any attempt to read or write them will create a BUS ERROR interrupt.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Regarding 68000: Are you refering to reading 16-bit quantities from misalign addresses in a byte addressable space?  Which part of my answer are you referencing when you ask 'Is that really so?'

Comment: I mean, what IS a misaligned address? We can assume reading 16 bits from 0x0 is always aligned. Is reading 16 bits from 0x2 always aligned?  Even if the native word size is 32 bits?  (I know it's OK on 68000 and x86.)

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Oh, ok. An aligned address must be defined for the architecture, but all architectures consider even multiples of a word's addressable size to be aligned. I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: But what is "even"... :)  Just because we have determined bytes to be *the* addressable unit of choice, it doesn't mean the CPU *must* have. Some CPUs even had 9 bits. And what is a word...

Comment: I finally updated the question to ask for something really tangible.

Comment: ", with a 32-bit word size, then you could never actually address only 16 bits anyway"   Counter example sort of; 68000 can not address odd 8 bit values. Yet in C, we merrily use char arrays. The compiler hides stuff from us. I was wondering if any CPU/C compiler in use hides even more alignment from us. This hiding has a performance cost.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant When I said "with a 32-bit word size", I meant "with a 32-bit addressable word size".  I was talking about the case where 32 bits is the least addressable unit.  Please note that I have answered your new question.