# What's the purpose of the casts to signed int in glibc memmove?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, glibc

[Source code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/memmove.c;h=f0a145eacda351833194dd64c301bf827f482c69;hb=HEAD#l44)

There they do

```
unsigned long int dstp = (long int) dest;
unsigned long int srcp = (long int) src;

/* This test makes the forward copying code be used whenever possible.
   Reduces the working set.  */
if (dstp - srcp >= len)       /* *Unsigned* compare!  */
  {
    /* Copy from the beginning to the end.  */
```

I understand why they go through the trouble of casting to longs in the first place: it is to avoid Undefined Behavior by comparing pointers to (probably) different objects. And they obviously have to use unsigned longs to do the actual comparison.

But why do they cast to `long int` first, then implicitly to `unsigned long int`?

Comment: It's an old bit-hack. You can check whether a signed value is the range of `0 <= a < b`, assuming `b` is positive, with a single comparison by converting a signed two's complement value to its unsigned counterpart since any negative `a` end up very large. It's not portable, of course, but then a runtime library doesn't have to be. Essentially `memmove` wants to know whether `dstp >= srcp && dstp <= srcp + len` to determine whether a fallback backwards copy must be made.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, addresses are unsigned, and my problem is with an entirely self-contained line of code:

    `unsigned long int dstp = (long int) dest;`

Why cast to signed first, only then to unsigned?

Comment: Ah, I apologize. It seems I misread the question. At a guess it is either a harmless relic from earlier factoring or a GCC-specific way of coaxing the optimizer along. I don't know that I read too much into  implementation-specific code.

Comment: @JohnSmith, C does not have addresses, it has pointers, which are neither signed nor unsigned.  Pointers can be *converted* to and from either signed or unsigned integers, but C does not specify the details.  Only by relying on implementation details can you assume that the result of a pointer-to-integer conversion is an address in the process's memory space.  And indeed, I think *implementation details* are the entire point.  If the casts serve any purpose at all, it is by virtue of details of (one of) the targeted runtime(s).

Comment: ["Sat Feb 15 12:53:02 1992 ... Make DSTP and SRCP unsigned (safer with non-ANSI compilers)"](https://github.com/Xilinx/eglibc/blob/master/ChangeLog.1)

Comment: Is that code still in use? Looks like trouble on 64 bit L32LLP64 systems.

Comment: "it is to avoid Undefined Behavior by comparing pointers to (probably) different objects"   - I doubt this is the reason.  Many things in this function are undefined behaviour according to the C Standard.  glibc targets a narrow range of platforms and relies on specific compiler behaviour of gcc which is not covered by the C Standard.  For example `(long int) dest` would cause UB in 64-bit Windows.

Comment: ` len -= (-dstp) % OPSIZ;` strongly depends on 2's complement representation. And I wonder of operator % is that well defined at that time.

Comment: @user3528438 "` len -= (-dstp) % OPSIZ;` strongly depends on 2's complement representation." -- the C standard demands that all operations on unsigned types follow two's complement arithmetic when it matters. Including casts from signed types, by the way.

Comment: Conversion to unsigned from signed *integral* types does modulo reduction, but out-of-range conversion from floating-point types is UB.  If pointers don't count as integral (or some "non-ANSI" compilers treat it differently), that might be relevant, IDK.  I'd still expect it to just preserve the bit-pattern if unsigned long is pointer-width.  (Which it normally is on a GNU system, unlike Windows x64)

Answer (score 2):

First, the parameters passed into the function are of type `void*` and `const void*`. In order to determine the addresses in a way that is comparable, they are cast to an integer type (`long int`). This first cast does an integer conversion so that the `void*` pointers can be compared numerically.

Second, some non-ANSI compilers may implement implicit casts from `void*` to integer types in a non-uniform manner and may lose some precision. On many platforms, the size of a `long` is the same as the size of a `void*` (though this is not true on all platforms), and casting from a `void*` to a `long` is an appropriate way to represent an address.

Third, the conversion from `long int` to `unsigned long int` serves two purposes: to ensure that large addresses are not mistaken as negative numbers during comparison, and to allow better safety for non-ANSI compilers. The function you are referencing in your code is concerned with memory alignment and overlapping memory regions in `dest` and `src` and to determine whether the memory movement will go from beginning to end or end to beginning. Unsigned comparisons are used here to better evaluate that possibility of overlapping memory regions, and how to handle it appropriately.

Some non-ANSI compilers may not properly convert directly from `void*` to `unsigned long int` (depending on implementation) and may truncate the pointer. The cast from `void*` to `long int` to `unsigned long int` should preserve the bit representation at each step so that the actual address is not corrupted.

Comment: This explains why the pointers are converted to an integer type, and explains why the variable type is `unsigned long int` rather than `long int`, but doesn't explain why the pointers aren't converted straight to `unsigned long int`, so doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: This doesn't really address why the code wouldn't cast to `unsigned long` directly.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I alluded to it in the second point (with non-ANSI compilers converting in a non-uniform manner), but I explicitly expanded on that in the last paragraph.

Comment: Err... Is that update a guess, or do you have something to support it? I would be very surprised by it. (Note in particular that the changelog entry mentioned in the comments on the question doesn't support it.)

Comment: [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7a53421-9f76-41e0-bd16-513e87d6526c/how-to-correctly-type-cast-void?forum=vclanguage) looks to be an instance where the compiler generates a warning regarding truncation between `void*` and `unsigned long`. It may be related to the 32/64 bit differing sizes for `long` and `void*`.

Comment: Okay, that's not applicable to the code in question here, and even if it were, the intermediate cast to `long` would not have any effect, as `long` and `unsigned long` always have the same size. If a conversion from a pointer to one of them truncates, the conversion from the same pointer to the other truncates as well.

Answer (score -4):

Someone copying a string with an odd length would be copying say 613 bytes,
but memcpy() is implemented in 32bit chunks for speed.

Some older processors like the 68000 crash if you write a 32bit integer to an odd address.

The casting is done for safety.  The work is done by the assembler, adding extra pad bytes if needed to prevent this.

Comment: More on this *here* **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869228/read-odd-addresses-half-words**

Comment: That's not what I'm asking about, my problem is with an entirely self-contained line of code:

      `unsigned long int dstp = (long int) dest;`

Why cast to signed first, only then to unsigned?

Comment: Looking at your source code that you posted, there are many comments about alignment being one of the primary reasons. But aside from that, the parameters passed into the function are declared as `void*` and `const void*` and need to be converted into a comparable integer type (in this case, `long int`) before they can be reinterpreted as `unsigned long int`. (`a1` and `a2` are `#define` macros that expand to `dest` and `src`, respectively.)

Comment: As an aside how is **long int** different from **long** , both are 32bits I presume ?

Comment: @ArifBurhan, `long int` and `long` are the same type.  The number of value bits in that type is implementation-defined, but it must be at least 31 (plus one sign bit).  It often is exactly 31.

Comment: I meant sizeof is 32 bits for both.

Comment: @ArifBurhan, I don't think you did, or at least you should not have done.  C permits integer types to contain padding bits, which count toward the size of objects of those types, but contribute nothing to the value.  From a language-lawyer perspective, it is the signedness and the number of value bits that matters here.

Comment: In any case, although the phenomenon you describe is real and well-documented, I don't see how it bears on the reason, if any, for the casts.